# How to use the "source" command in Zsh

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh

I'm working inside a Zsh terminal on a Mac.

I'm trying to use the `source` command so that I can just call my script by name, rather than typing the path to the ".sh" script. The `source` command does not return any errors, but once I try calling the ".sh" file by name it returns "command not found."

I've also tried typing in the absolute path when using the `source` command, but with no luck.

Terminal commands:

```
source ~/Documents/marco.sh
marco
zsh: command not found: marco
```

marco.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  
touch ~/Documents/marco.txt
echo $(pwd) > ~/Documents/marco.txt
```

Comment: `source` doesn't make the script available by name; it just executes each command in the given file in the current shell, as opposed to in a new process.

Comment: You could simply add `~/Documents` to your `PATH` variable, in which case you could run `marco.sh`. If you `marco` alone to work, you'll need to define an alias, or a function, or create a symlink to `~/Documents/marco.sh` in one of your PATH directories, etc.

Comment: Don't run commands from the Documents directory. Instead, create a `~/bin` directory, add it to your `PATH` near the front, and put the command in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it exactly the way you want to, you can make a `marco` function:

```
# marco.sh
marco () {
  touch ~/Documents/marco.txt
  echo $(pwd) > ~/Documents/marco.txt
}
```

Then you `source` it and run `marco`. If you're going to use this a lot, I suggest putting the function in `.zshrc` or another file that will be sourced by your shell automatically.

And as suggested in comments, you could also put your original `marco.sh` in your path. I like to use `~/bin` for these types of personal executables:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ mv ~/Documents/marco.sh ~/bin
$ export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
$ marco.sh
```

Again, put the `export PATH` line in your `.zshrc` or similar file.